# Firestore Query Properties with special characters

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've a collection with contacts with a structure like:

`name: 'XPTO'
emails: { susan@xpto.com: 'Susan', fred@xpto.com: 'Fred' }`

But the query will not return result:
`db.firestore().collection('contacts').where('emails.susan@xpto.com', '==', 'Susan').get().then(...`

Because of the dot at "susan@xpto.com"

How to escape the dot?

I've tried ``` `` ``` and `[ ]` and didn't work.

Comment: Your call to `where` doesn't look valid.  It takes three arguments, not one.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#where

Comment: Sorry Doug, I didn't copy the code correctly. But the problem is the dot on the email. If I create a field without the dot and query like that, it will return the result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The documentation that suggests you should escape fields using backticks is actually not correct.  It's in the process of being fixed.  Instead, you should use [FieldPath](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/FieldPath) to build a path to the field to query:

```
db.firestore()
.collection('contacts')
.where(new FieldPath('emails', 'susan@xpto.com'), '==', 'Susan').
```

Comment: Thanks Doug.
I'm web developing, so if it helps here's the web version:
    db.firestore().collection('contacts').where(new db.firestore.FieldPath('emails', 'susan@xpto.com'), '==', 'Susan').

Comment: Another variation for Web JS: `.where(new firebase.firestore.FieldPath('users', emailAddress), '==', true);`

Comment: Saving the day yet again Doug!